# Why isn't my data persisting after using SavedStateHandle?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am writing an app that stores a value after it get killed by the user. It is stored in the `ViewModel` and saved in the `onClear` function. I want to be able to reopen the app and see the saved value but when I access this value with the specified key, it comes back as null. Here is my code

```
package com.example.sharedexpenseapp

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header

class MainActivityViewModel constructor (private val savedState: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        private const val NAME= "NAME"
    }

    //LiveData for HomePageFragment
    private val liveName = MutableLiveData<String>(getName().value)
    internal val name: LiveData<String>
        get() = liveName

    internal val orientation = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    internal var navController: NavController? = null

    //LiveData for LoginFragment
    internal val liveNameEditText = MutableLiveData<String>()

    internal fun saveName(name: String?) { liveName.value = name; name?.let { savedState.set(NAME, it) }}

    private fun getName(): MutableLiveData<String> { return savedState.getLiveData(NAME) }

    override fun onCleared() {
        liveName.value?.let { saveName(it) }
        super.onCleared()
    }

}
```

Most of the functions in my code have been omitted but the savedState part is included. Is there anything that I am doing wrong or misunderstanding?

**EDIT:**
I now understand that `SavedStateHandle` only persists when the system kills the process. Instead of using `SavedStateHandle`, is there any other data type or technique that I can use to save data after the user closes the app?

Comment: As per official doc, With SavedStateHandle "These values will persist after the process is killed by the system and remain available via the same object." not after user kills the app.https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle

Comment: Is there any data type that I can use to persist after the user kills the app?

Comment: you can use SharedPreference or local DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle) on `SavedStateHandle`

> These values will persist after the process is killed by the system
> and remain available via the same object.

not after user kills the app.

You can either store data in `SharedPreference` or local DB

Comment: Either Room, or Jetpack DataStore (currently alpha) should help

Comment: Yes @EpicPandaForce